# Weird Memory Problems with Memtest86 Results

Tags: memory, hardware-failure, diagnostic, ddr3, memtest86+

I'm having some trouble with one of my memory modules. The unit in question is a GSkill F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL. I started noticing my computer was acting up yesterday when I started getting artifacts whilst playing Sins of a Solar Empire. When I come back to the desktop, I see that my virus scan has quarantined some trojan (I didn't pay much attention unfortunately to its name) and other stuff labelled as low risk and promptly delete them.

Now comes the weird part. I'm on firefox and it starts crashing with increasing frequency. Eventually, I can't even start it or any program for that matter. I get worried and try to scan with microsoft security essentials, but after it gets to some nvidia driver file, the whole thing; definition updates and real time protection, just implodes. Then come the blue screens. Fantastic. I notice that every time I try to scan it always gets stuck at that same nvidia driver file.

Next, I get some advice from the helpful fellows at bleepingcomputer.com telling me to run rootkit removal tools and other diagnostics. I try to do all this in safe mode. I don't get any hits and all the while the computer is going cuckoo for cocoa puffs, blue screening right and left. Eventually, I can't even boot into safe mode because it gets hung up at classpnp.sys and I wonder if I managed to get infected with the honey badger of computer worms.

After some more searching for advice, I boot up with Memtest86. Immediately, I start getting errors. I test each stick individually and find a (hopefully the singular) culprit. This thing has managed to rack up more than 100000 errors on just one pass. Although I can boot with both sticks individually, the faulty one eventually bluescreens when I try to run a virus scan. I don't think I've ever been so relieved to have a part fail. Has anyone had similar problems like this? Also, what have your guys' RMA experience with GSkill been like? Thanks and take care.

Comment: It sounds like you have memory problems, bad drivers, and a trojan. Just replace your RAM and reinstall the entire OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, RMA the failing modules. You might need to send all three because they are paired.